# Close all GUI:s if main GUI is closing

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I can close my main gui with a menu or the x button

```
function menuProgramQuit_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
close(handles.figure1);
```

However at the same time a sub gui dialog might be open

```
function pushbuttonCalibrationConfigure_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
calibrationOutput = uiConfigureCalibration('uiMain', handles.figure1);
waitfor(calibrationOutput);
guidata(handles.output,handles);
```

If the main figure was close the sub gui is not and further it crashes when he subgui (here 
`uiConfigureCalibration`) is closed, because the figure handle of the main gui is invalid.

So how can I close all sub guis in matlab before I close the main gui ?

EDIT:
I changed the code such that the called dialog saves its handle to the handles of the main dialog

```
function uiConfigureCalibration_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% Choose default command line output for uiConfigureCalibration
handles.output = hObject;
% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
% save handle of calling gui
mainGuiHandleIndex = find(strcmp(varargin, 'uiMain'));
if ~isempty(mainGuiHandleIndex)
    handles.mainHandle = varargin{mainGuiHandleIndex+1};
    handlesMain = guidata(handles.mainHandle);
    handlesMain.('openfigures').('calibration') = handles.figure1;
    guidata(handles.mainHandle, handlesMain);
    guidata(handles.figure1, handles);
end
```

In the closing function in the main gui I can no check if the figure us open and close it before the main figure is closed

```
if isfieldRecursive(handles, 'handles.openfigures.calibration') 
    close(handles.openfigures.calibration);
end
close(handles.figure1);
```

That however changes nothing. The sub-dialog figure is only closed AFTER the main dialog closes and the whole code crashes again.

Why is the figure of the sub dialog NOT closed with the close command?

Comment: Did you try `close(handle)` or even `close(all)` ?

Comment: I did not try `close(all)`. I need to ensure that all sub guis are closed before the main gui and I am sure that this is not necessarily the case with `close(all)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `CloseRequestFcn` `figure` property.

This will let you intercept the requests to delete a figure and then handle those requests as you see fit.

Here is a simple function that illustrates how to use the `CloseRequestFcn` to achieve the behavior you are describing above:

```
function figTest()

f1 = figure('UserData', 1, 'Position', [100 500 50 50]);
f2 = figure('UserData', 2, 'Position', [200 500 50 50]);

set(f1,'CloseRequestFcn', @preCloseMain);

function preCloseMain(src, e)


  % Delete f2, in try-block incase it was already closed
  try 
    fprintf('Closing non-main figures!\n');
    close(f2);
  end 
  fprintf('Closing main figure!\n');     
  delete(src);
end

end
```

Here are [the official docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/the-figure-close-request-function.html).

Comment: I do this already, only a but more complicated with `close(handles.openfigures.calibration);` but this does NOT close the window. The window is only closed AFTER the main gui is closed and thus the code crashes. So your code has the same problem as mine.

Comment: Why do you set the `CloseRequestFcn` for f1 and not for the main figure handle ? I ask, because I do not understand how to adapt your example to my code. I would add the call to the perCloseMain to the init function of the main gui.

Comment: Simple examples at better on forums like this because they are easier to read and adapt. Simply replace the `CloseRequestFcn` on your main figure handle.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, I wanted to close all the existing GUI windows when opening the main window.

I write an `.m` function:

```
function closeAll()
clear all, close all, fclose('all'), clc, warning('off','MATLAB:xlswrite:AddSheet'); %   close all opened items and clear Matlab workspace
end
```

and call this function in the GUI OpeningFcn or anywhere it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where my gui would spawn other guis, namely an option gui and a log gui.  In my main app I had things like this.

```
logFH = CreateLog;
optFH = CreateOptions;
```

These functions would create figures and return the handles.  The handles can be saved in gui handles or with `setappdata` and `getappdata`.  Later when I would close the main function.

```
if (isgraphics(logFH))
    close(logFH);
    delete(logFH);
end
```